# Remote Desktop Connection stopped working - It connects, but no window shows up

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, connection

**So my setup is this:**

I have my laptop here, where i do my work on. I also got a standard PC, where i have everything connected to. On both i got windows 10 installed. The last update on the laptop was from the 10.02.2021, while my PC updated this morning (15.02.2021). But i also tried other pc's in the household (last updates on 11.02) with the same problem.

Usually i connect to the laptop via remote-desktop. It always worked perfectly.

**The problem:**

Today i did the same, but after some time the window literally vanished. Trying to connect again via remote-desktop shows the message (german: "Remote Verbindung wird gesichert"). Afterwards it should connect, but the message-window literally vanishes. There is no error-message showing. It just goes back to the remote desktop login-window (where i write the IP).

**Informations:**

The first strange thing is this: After connecting with Remote desktop, the laptop normally goes into the login-screen (probably because i'm loginned from the PC). The same happens here too BUT: After a login on the laptop itself from this screen (i call this the fake login, because it doesnt login?), it goes straight back to the login-screen again. Login in a second time shows the usual desktop.

The eventviewer shows this timeline:

When i "connect" with the remote desktop it shows a user login in "security" and "application". It immediately shows a logoff in "security" in the same second and an error like "The windows-login-process was unexpectedly closed" in "application".

When i "fake" login it shows a login and logoff in "security".

The real login only shows the login in security.

I feel like the remote desktop connects, but just doesn't show the screen (on 2 pc's, so i assume the laptop is the culprit and not the pc's).

**What i tried:**

Obviously some restarts. I also tried disabling and enabling to allow the remote desktop connections.

Another thing i tried is disabling the firewalls.

Also i tried to disable the permanent bitmapsaving from the connecting PC.